# Proper usage of abstract classes or interfaces in the following situation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, abstract-class, repository-pattern

I have different types of documents: DocumentCitizen, DocumentOther, DocumentResolution etc. There're also corresponding repositories for each of the document types: DocumentCitizenRepository,DocumentOtherRepository,DocumentResolutionRepository. All the repositories have a property called Documents and a method called SaveDocument. Here's the content of the DocumentCitizenRepository as an example:

```
public class DocumentCitizenRepository{

   EFDbContext context= new EFDbContext();//EFDbContext inherits DbContext        
   public IQueryable<DocumentCitizen> Documents{get{context.DocmentsFromCitizens}}
   public void SaveDocument(DocumentCitizen doc)
   {//omitted for brevity}
}
```

The contents of the other repositories are similar.For this reason I would like all the repositories extend an abstract class called Repository. I've also defined an abstract class for all the document types called Document with empty content:

```
public abstract class Document{}

public abstract class Repository{
  public abstract IQueryable<Document>{get;}
  public abstract void SaveDocument(Document doc)
}
```

But I get warning about invalid or missing overriding because the compiler needs signatures of the properties and methods be the same. To see the difference:

The method in the base abstract class:

```
  public abstract void SaveDocument(Document doc)
```

and the one in the inheriting class:

```
  public abstract void SaveDocument(DocumentCitizen doc)
```

So I'm totally confused as to whether it's possible to do what I want. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are you using an ORM (Entity Framework)?

Comment: Yes, I do use Entity Framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you can even go a step further and create a completely generic base repo:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> GetQueryable();
    void Save(T item);
}

public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    public IQueryable<T> GetQueryable() { ... }
    public void Save(T item) { ... }
}
```

You would still have specific repository interfaces which would allow you to create methods specific for an entity:

```
public interface IDocumentCitizenRepository : IRepository<DocumentCitizen>
{ 
    // this interface has no extra methods, just the plain ol' CRUD
}

public interface IDocumentResolutionRepository : IRepository<DocumentResolution>
{ 
    // this one can do additional stuff
    void DoSomethingSpecial(DocumentResolution doc);
}
```

And the abstract base class is used to reuse the common functionality:

```
// this class will inherit everything from the base abstact class
public class DocumentCitizenRepository 
   : BaseRepository<DocumentCitizen>, IDocumentCitizenRepository
{ }

// this class will inherit common methods from the base abstact class,
// and you will need to implement the rest manually
public class DocumentResolutionRepository 
   : BaseRepository<DocumentResolution>, IDocumentResolutionRepository
{ 
    public void DoSomethingSpecial(DocumentResolution doc)
    {
        // you still need to code some specific stuff every once in a while
    }
}
```

This is then usually used with dependency injection, so that you only use interfaces in your business layer without caring about actual implementations:

```
var repo = container.Resolve<IDocumentCitizenRepository>();
repo.Save(doc);
```

This last part (dependency injection) should be ideally done in the composition root, meaning that using a container directly all over your code (the "service locator" pattern) is not the ideal way of abstracting these dependencies. Try to organize your classes to receive repository interfaces through constructors, which will allow you do mock each repo easily when doing unit testing.

Comment: That's really cool. But do I really need that Interface? Isn't the generic abstract class alone enough?

Comment: Interfaces allow you to keep the option of having repository-specific methods which cannot be extracted into a base class (at the cost of a bit of extra complexity, of course). Sometimes it's handy to be able to do a more complex query through the repo, other than basic CRUD operations. Even if you choose to have a common repo interface for all entities (e.g. only `IRepository<T>`), you shouldn't simply create new instances of `BaseRepository<T>` all over the place because you will create tight coupling and prevent unit testing (mocking the db access).

Answer (score 1):

I usually tend to do something like the following:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T: class
{
  bool Delete(T entity);
  bool Save(T entity);
}
```

You can then use the repo...

```
private IRepository<DocumentCitizen> _docCitizen;
```

in your methods, you can all the repo like...

```
DocumentCitizen doc = new DocumentCitizen{....}
_docCitizen.Save(doc);
```

You could pass this as a constructor argument...

```
public DocumentService(
            IRepository<DocumentCitizen> docCitizen)
        {
            _docCitizen = docCitizen;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it does not make sense to make `DocumentCitizenRepository` inherit its `Save` method from an single abstract `DocumentRepository` class, since a `DocumentCitizenRepository` cannot save arbitrary documents. By inheriting the method you violate the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

For a `GetDocuments` method, the matter is different. A `DocumentCitizenRepository.GetDocuments ()` returns a specific kind of documents, which, if `DocumentCitizen` inherits from `Document`, can be treated as documents, and thus, `DocumentCitizenRepository.GetDocuments ()` is a valid implementation of some `DocumentRepository.GetDocuments ()` method.

Approach:

```
class DocumentCitizenRepository : DocumentRepository<DocumentCitizen> {
   public override void Save (DocumentCitizen doc) { ... }
   public override IEnumerable<DocumentCitizen> GetDocuments () { ... }
}

// this class is only meant to simplify implementation
abstract class DocumentRepository<T> : IDocumentRepository where T: Document {
   public abstract void Save (T doc);
   public abstract IEnumerable<T> GetDocuments ();
   IEnumerable<Document> IDocumentRepository.GetDocuments () { return this.GetDocuments (); }
}

interface IDocumentRepository {
   IEnumerable<Document> GetDocuments ();
}
```